# Efficiently forward content from internal HttpClient call in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I'm calling an internal HTTP service from my ASP.NET Core app. The response messages from this service can be very large, so I want to forward them as efficiently as possible. If possible I just want to "map" the content to the controller response - or in other words "pipe the stream comming from the service to the stream going out of my controller".

My controller method so far simply calls the service:

```
[HttpPost]
public Post([FromBody]SearchQuery searchQuery)
{
    var response = _searchClient.Search(searchQuery);
    // ?
}
```

The service is called by an HttpClient instance. Here (as an example) I just return the HttpContent, but of course I could return the completely read and serialised body (which I obviously don't want):

```
public async Task<HttpContent> Search(SearchQuery searchQuery)
{
    var content = new StringContent(TsearchQuery, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("_search", content);
    return response.Content;
}
```

Is it efficient and fast to return the content? How would I pass the content in my controller method to the response? Does ASP.NET Core create streams underneath? Or should I handle streams in my code explicitly?

Answer (score 16):

You can just return the `Stream` from the action and ASP.NET Core MVC will efficiently write it to the response body.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<Stream> Post([FromBody]SearchQuery searchQuery)
{
    var response = await _searchClient.Search(searchQuery);
    return await response.ReadAsStreamAsync();
}
```

Comment: Nitpick but `ReadAsStreamAsync` instead of `ReadAsStream` seems redundant here unless you plan on doing something with the `Stream`.

Answer (score 4):

From my experience, passing through the response stream as David suggested works, but does not maintain the HTTP status code. You'd have to add this line:

```
Response.StatusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44737128/196564) provides an alternative way of copying a complete HttpResponseMessage.